# Changing admin menu class not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make admin navigation. When I click a menu it will be active until I click another menu. When I click another menu that should then be active. In my admin nav, I used the below code but it is not working. All my CSS is working properly, but I can't set the clicked menu as active. How I can fix this problem?

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
    .admin-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.admin-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    transition: .4s;
}

.admin-menu ul li a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.admin-menu ul li:hover, li.active {
    background-color: #F8694A !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="admin-nav">
  <div class="admin-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i> Category</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> E-books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i> Orders</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-layer-group"></i> Others</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not entirely clear? What is the expected behavior and what actually happens? You say you "can't active currently click menu". What do you mean by that?

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet (and added the `.active` class), and it appears to work absolutely fine. Please check your console for errors, and ensure that your `.active` class is specific enough to override any existing rules on the `li` elements.

Comment: In a production environment, the links would take the user to different pages, right?

Comment: Does your console spit out an error?

Comment: `This code is working here properly at snippet, but not working in my browser.` Why this problem occurs, I don't know.

Comment: As I, and others, have said in previous comments you need to check the console for errors. Press F12 to open it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in my console I find to like this https://imgur.com/a/WhDU14D